# Simultaneous equation with fractional solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do you get to find $x$ when $y$ is a fraction ? Anyone mind to explain it step by step for the clearest explanation.=)

$$-7x +2y = 2$$
$$14x + 3y = -5$$

Answer: $x=?, y=-1/7$

Comment: your answer is correct but i don't know how to get X step by step with fraction of Y. Sorry if this is dumb question.

Comment: By Cramer's rule, the determinants are integers and the solutions are rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Inserting $y=-\frac{1}{7}$ in the first equation*

$-7x-2\cdot \frac{1}{7}=2$

Transforming 2 into $\frac{14}{7}$ to have a common denominator with $2\cdot \frac{1}{7}$

$-7x-\frac{2}{7}=\frac{14}{7} \quad \quad |+\frac{2}{7}$

Adding $\frac{2}{7}$ on both sides.

$-7x\underbrace{-\frac{2}{7}+\color{blue}{\frac{2}{7}}}_{=0}=\frac{14}{7} +\color{blue}{\frac{2}{7}}$

$-7x+0=\frac{14}{7} +\color{blue}{\frac{2}{7}}$

$-7x=\frac{14}{7}+\frac{2}{7}$

$-7x=\frac{16}{7}$

$-x=\frac{16}{7\cdot 7}$

$x=-\frac{16}{49}$

Comment: i know how to calculate the last 4 step but don't know how to calculate the first two step like -2 1/7=2 . Sorry and isn't it 15/7 with 2*7+1=15? I'm confused as how to calculate the first two step. =(

Comment: First  $\frac{2}{7}$ and 7 have to have a common denominator. This is 7. And $2=\frac{2}{1}$ Now you expand the fraction by 7. $\frac{2\cdot 7}{1\cdot 7}=\frac{14}{7}$ Therefore you are able to add $\frac{14}{7}$ and $\frac{2}{7}$: $\frac{14}{7}+\frac{2}{7}=\frac{16}{7}$

Comment: ok i get it,we move over the 1/7 to right side which is equal to 2/7 and left hand side of 2*7 become 14/7?  IS that how to calculate?

Comment: Thank you. I just confuse with certain element of fraction like mixed number which need to multiply and add. =)

Comment: Not really. You move $\frac{2}{7}$ to the right side by adding $\frac{2}{7}$ on both sides. On the left side the calculation is $-\frac{2}{7}-\frac{2}{7}=0$ And on the right side you transform 2 into $\frac{14}{7}$ and add  $\frac{2}{7}$

Comment: but you have only one -2/7 in left side? I thought you just move 1/7 to right and became 2/7 and left side 2 transform into 14/7 by *7 since both denominator need to be 7 ? How to get two times of -2/7?

Comment: Oh, i'm wrong. You need to move right hand side of 2 to the left first and became -2/7 then the left hand side of -2 became 14/7 by *7 in numerator and denominator then only move both to right hand side. Is that correct?

Comment: I have made an edit. I hope it will clarify all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution to your system of equations is $y = -\frac{1}{7}$ and you want to find $x$. To do so, substitute this value of $y$ into the first equation to get $$-7x - 2\cdot \frac{1}{7} = 2 \iff -7x = \frac{16}{7} \iff x = -\frac{16}{49}$$ by re-arranging and solving for $x$.

Alternatively, you could substitute your $y$ value into the second equation to get $$14x - 3\cdot \frac{1}{7} = -5 \iff 14x = -\frac{32}{7} \iff x = -\frac{16}{49}$$ by re-arranging and solving for $x$.

So the solution to your system of equations is $x = -\frac{16}{49}, y = -\frac{1}{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

The answers of @calculus and @ZainPatel are perfect, but I would like to offer a slicker method, if you don’t like working with fractions.

Perform the same first step as they do, namely substitute your known value of $y$ into the first equation, getting
$$
-7x-2\cdot\frac17=2\,,
$$
and multiply both sides of the equation by $7$, thus cleaering of fractions:
$$-49x-2=14\,.$$
This gives $49x=-16$, the rest is clear.